# Issue with Docker installation on Linux

Tags: linux, docker, rhel

I am trying to install Docker on RHEL whose version details are shown below

[image]

I have downloaded the rpm docker-ce-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64.rpm from [here](https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/). And I run the following install command

```
sudo yum install /home/projuser/usr/share/Docker/docker-ce-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Error comes up suggesting that *docker-ce-rootless-extras* is required.

```
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64 (/docker-ce-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64)
Requires: docker-ce-rootless-extras
```

Here is the full screenshot of error

[image]

As per the message I try to install *docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64.rpm* that I downloaded from [here](https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/) using command shown below

```
sudo yum install /home/projuser/usr/share/Docker/docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I get an error that suggests that *docker-ce* is required

```
Error: Package: docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64 (/docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64)
Requires: docker-ce
```

Here is the complete screenshot

[image]

So I am not sure how to resolve this dependency as docker-ce and docker-ce-rootless-extras are both not getting installed with dependency on each other. Please let me know if you need any other details.

Please help resolve this

Comment: Why don't you use just `sudo yum install docker`?

Comment: @roman-pavelka Running `sudo yum install docker` indicates that the docker package isn't found    --> `Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, langpacks, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                                                               | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.7-rpms                                                                                                           | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
No package docker available.`

Comment: I sadly can't test it now, but check https://serverfault.com/questions/1022860/not-able-to-install-docker-on-redhat Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Hope it not too late. You have to install both packages at the same time.

> rpm -i docker-ce-XXXXX docker-ce-rootless-extras-XXXXX

This command is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the centos package on RHEL. installing the correct package resolved the same issue I was facing. check out this [Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427665/error-starting-docker-service-unit-not-found)